# How do I left join and get only rows from a specific attribute in linq C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

i want to make it straight forward because i tried a lot of stuff and none of them seems to work for me.

```
Categories = await  _context.Categories.ToListAsync(),
            CategorySubjects = await _context.CategorySubjects
            .Include(s => s.Books.Where( == true))
            .ToListAsync(),
Books = await _context.Books.Where(b => b.Active == true).ToListAsync()
```

I have this piece of code where i want to get all categorysubjects with all books in them where the active of book is true and this is the equivalent of it in sql

```
select *
from CategorySubjects
    left join Books on  CategorySubjects.Id = Books.CategorySubjectId
where Books.Active = 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: That LEFT JOIN returns regular INNER JOIN result anyway... Move the Books.Active condition from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result. (Simply replace WHERE with AND.)

Comment: Yes i get that in sql, but i cant get the result in c#

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) could help you?